# Debug cpp programs in Visual Studio after cloning the files from github

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github, visual-c++

I cloned a respiratory from Github using Visual Studio, then created a README.md file. Later the file pushed to Github and everything went well. In VisualStudio, I created a simple C++ file "Hello.cpp" from Solution explorer but I am not able to debug this file. Whenever I debug it's showing "Please select a valid startup item". I opened the file from F:C++\Demo2\Hello.cpp then while debugging its showing "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run with the last successful build?". I'm new to GitHub and visual studio so I just need to know how to normally create files in visual studio after cloning it? Is there any difficulties while doing it? Is there any simple solution to create and edit files?
"I know how to push files to github"

Comment: project file/settings tells vs what executable to run for a project.  solution settings tells it what project to run if one is not specified.  If starting out, I suggest making a solution and a new project from their hello world template and taking a look at its project properties.

Comment: Normally on github I use CMake to generate VS project files and don't put the VS project file into the github repository since anyone else would not have the same paths as me. They can use CMake to generate their own project file. Also perhaps they are using XCode or Qt-Creator instead of Visual Studio Community. With CMake they can generate project files for those as well. With that said CMake is not something you learn in a day. It's a lot of work but worthwhile for me.

Comment: ***"Please select a valid startup item"*** Right click on the project in Solution Explorer that is a project that is executable and click "set as startup project". Whatever project you have currently selected is not an application that can be run.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, I saw the same thing while looking for answers, but when I right-click I couldn't find any option like "set as startup project". That's why I went to open the file separately but the whole VS window restarted and displayed the same code panel again and I started to see the new message "There were build errors..."

Answer (score 2):

> In Visual Studio, I created a simple C++ file "Hello.cpp" from Solution explorer but I am not able to debug this file.

Could you please tell us if there are multiple projects in Solution Explorer? If so, you should set the startup project: right click the project you want to start,and choose `Set as StartUp Project`.

[image]

> That's why I went to open the file separately

Could you please tell us you directly opened a .cpp file? As far as I'm concerned you should open a .sln file (File > Open > project/Solution and found the ".sln" file.) instead of a .cpp file.

> "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run with the last successful build?"

This error message means there has some error in your code. When you click yes, it will run the correct code which has compiled successful before current modified code, which why you will not see the most recent edits. And when you click no, it will stop debug to let you modify the error code.

For this error message, we often choose No to stop run our application and then modify the error code. You can check the error code from Error List windows from View menu -> Error List

Comment: In my VS Solution Explorer, I can only see few options. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bbI2QKAMBpwRCmdVm-9sQrlbxMJvkd0P/view?usp=sharing
Here is my requirement, I want to create basic cpp program examples and I want to push it into a single Github repository folder. The cpp files should be editable so I can add notes later.

Comment: @RamdasRajan You could only run the .sln file (Visual Studio Solution) not a .cpp file. I suggest you could refer to the link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/67613360/11872808