# Visual Studio: Unable to start program, the system cannot find the file specified visual studio error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, visual-studio-2019

Here I'm Using visual studio 2019 community edition. I open a folder from file->new->existing project. But whenever i build and run my program. it says

> Unable to start program 'O:\1.Fourth
> semester\programminh\main\Debug\Main2.exe'
> the system cannot find the file specified

There are lots of programs. like bubble.cpp, binary.cpp but it runs Main2.exe.

**Here is my linear.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

            int n, an, arr[30], key, i, found=0;
            cout<<"Please enter number of element you want:"<<endl;

            cin>>n;
            cout<<"Please enter the numbers"<<endl;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                cin>>arr[i];
            }


            cout<<"Please Enter the number you want to search"<<endl;
            cin>>key;

            for(i=0;i<n; i++){

                if(arr[i] == key){
                    cout<<"Element found at position "<<i+1;

                    found=1;
                    break;
                }
                }


                if(!found){
                    cout<<"Number Not Found"<<endl;
                }








            return 0;


}
```

Can someone check it out, please?

Comment: The code seems to be compilable. ([Test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf05a7340b925fb9)). Hence, I guess your VS project is somehow incorrect configured. You didn't expose anything about this. However... MS has some (IMHO very good) tutorials on their web site. Maybe, you should start there first.

Comment: It's compilable. I run it in codeblocks. Its ok. But I got an error in the visual studio. and it runs the main.exe which I've created as project name even If i select bubble.cpp

Comment: _it runs the main.exe which I've created as project name even If i select bubble.cpp_ Of course, it does because that is how it's supposed to work. FYI: [MS: **Solutions and projects in Visual Studio**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Scheff Should it run bubble.cpp? There are lots of  cpp files. Shouldn't it run my target file? It's opening which program I ran at the first time.

Comment: Okay.. I will check it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I open a folder from file->new->existing project.

As far as I'm concerned you should open a .sln file instead of a folder.

You could only run the .sln file (Visual Studio Solution) not a .cpp file.

Comment: How can I create and open .sln folder visual. I have lots of CPP file in another folder and I've done it codeblocks. It runs fine in codeblocks but whenever I run it visual studio I got this error. I would like to open the folder from my existing folder and run every single file like codeblocks. How can I do that?

Comment: @Tusar Haque As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't run the .cpp in the Visual Studio. Visual Studio does not support this. A project is always required, even if it only contains a single source code (.cpp) file.

You could run a single .cpp source file through Microsoft's C++ compiler on the command line (cl.exe), and then execute it. But this doesn't involve anything about the Visual Studio IDE.